# Proving a property of a solution to a set of nonlinear polynomial equations

Tags: reference-request, generating-functions, nonlinear-system

Consider the following system of equations for $R_{i}(\lambda)$
\begin{align}
R_1 &= \frac{\lambda}{4}(1 + R_3 + 2 R_2 R_1)  \tag{1.1}\\ 
R_2 &= \lambda \left[q + \left(\frac{1}{2} - q\right)R_2 + q R_1 R_2 + \left(\frac{1}{2} - q \right) R_3 R_2 \right] \tag{1.2} \\ 
R_3 &= \lambda \left[\frac{1}{2} - q + q R_1 + q R_1 R_3 + \left(\frac{1}{2} - q \right) R_3^2 \right] \tag{1.3}
\end{align}
where $0 < q < 1/4$. The $R_i(\lambda)$ are generating functions arising in the study of a certain random walk, so they are analytic at least in $|\lambda| \leq 1$.

One can immediately see that there will be a solution to Eqs. $(1)$ with the property that $R_{i}(1) = 1$. Let the set of $R_{i}(\lambda)$ which satisfy Eq. $(1)$ and have $R_{i}(1) = 1$ be called the "basic" solution.

> Proposition 1. In the basic solution, there is at least one $i$ such that $R_{i}(\lambda = 1 - \epsilon) > 1$ for some $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Proof 1. One can see this by reducing Eqs. $(1)$ to a single quartic polynomial in $R_2$ and then solving with Mathematica. The result is a mess, but Proposition 1 is verified directly.

Proof 2. One can compute the derivatives $\text{d} R_i /\text{d}\lambda |_{\lambda = 1 - \epsilon}$ via implicit differentiation and show that they are negative.

> Question: I'm interested in showing Proposition 1 for other (bigger) systems like Eqs. $(1)$ so I'm looking for a more powerful proof technique. Is there any way to do this without actually solving the system or computing its derivatives?

Comment: Just to understand better what you are after, can you post an example of a "larger" system that is of interest to you? The example you posted is rather simple and reduces to showing that a certain matrix with positive entries has an eigenvalue bigger than $1$ by observing that if you apply it to the vector $(1,1,1)$, each coordinate goes up, so it may be not very representative of what you are actually struggling with.

Comment: Well, Eqs. (1) can be generalized a bit so the coefficients are arbitrary probabilities. So we would have the set of 12 equations
$$
R_{i, j}^{(\ell)} = \lambda(p_{i, j}^{(\ell)} + p_{i, k}^{(\ell)} R_{k, j}^{(\ell)} + p_{i, j}^{(-\ell)} R_{j, i}^{(-\ell)} R_{i, j}^{(\ell)} + p_{i, k}^{(-\ell)} R_{k, i}^{(-\ell)} R_{i, j}^{(\ell)} )
$$
where $(i, j, k)$ is a permutation of $(1, 2, 3)$ and $\ell = \pm 1$. We have $p_{i, j}^{(\ell)} + p_{i, k}^{(\ell)} + p_{i, j}^{(-\ell)} + p_{i, k}^{(-\ell)} = 1$.

Comment: Then the general answer is like this. Let $A$ be the differential of the  RHS. It is a matrix with non-negative entries, so its largest eigenvalue is positive. Assume that $I-A$ is invertible (so we have a smooth solution near $\lambda=1$ by the inverse function theorem). Then Proposition 1 holds if and only if the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than $1$. Without additional information about $p_{ij}^{(\ell)}$ that may or may not hold for your system.

Comment: @fedja Thanks for your follow-up, I was thinking the same thing. Earlier, I constructed the matrix of derivatives of the RHS and computed its spectral radius for $p_{i, j}^{(k)} \in (0, 1) $ chosen uniformly at random and found that it was greater than $1$ in all cases. So I'm even more convinced that Prop. 1 must be true but I still don't know how to actually show it. The classical lower bound on the spectral radius from the minimum row sum doesn't work because it's not a strict inequality and I believe the spectral radius can be arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: OK, I'll try to think of it then. All probabilities are strictly positive, right?

Comment: @fedja Yeah they're all in $(0, 1)$